# Symfony cant load css files

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Im having problems with loading my css and js files.

Css and js are in app/Resources/views/css and app/Resources/views/js folders

This is my app/Resources/views/base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../app/Resources/views/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../app/Resources/views/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        <!-- this also doesnt work ofcourse -->
        <script src="../app/Resources/views//js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../app/Resources/views//js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It cant find my files.

How should i solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: see the duplicate, you'll find your answer there. but also what lorenzSchaef said it's true as well

Answer (score 1):

Your "app" folder is outside the webroot and can't be accessed. Put the files in the "web" folder instead!